# Inheritance using Abstract class in GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I have following domain objects & I am using spring boot support for GraphQL.

```
public abstract class User {
    private long id;
    private String email;
}
public class Person extends User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //getters & setters
}
public class Company extends User {
    private String name;
    private String hqCity;
    //getters & setters
}
```

Now I want to fetch all users be it Person or Company. 
How would I do that using graphql schema ? I tried for interface in graphQL but that does not work. Does graphQL supports this in some way ?

Comment: You could certainly model this so that `User` is an interface in GraphQL and `Person` and `Company` are the implementations, and a query would return a list of `User`s. But since I have no idea how you actually create your schema I can't help you on how to do this.

Comment: right I did that. Then while starting the server I got error that "person does not implement User interface". Because, in actual User is not an interface.

Comment: Oh, so you're not composing the schema yourself but generating it somehow. Then it's up to whatever tool you're using to allow you to customize the mapping... Sorry, try asking on the graphql-java Gitter channel. Btw, graphql-spqr (my tool) enables this scenario for sure.

Comment: Ok,I will try your tool. One more question, if there is a class hierarchy like
class A extends B{}
class B extends C{}
where B & C are both abstract classes. Does your tool also take care of that, Can you please provide me some link to your tool & tutorial.

Comment: Moreover I created the graphql schema by myself i.e. handwritten not by any tool.

Comment: If you're writing the schema yourself, then there's no direct mapping between Java classes and GraphQL types. GraphQL knows nothing about the Java type system.  I don't understand how are you in this situation then...

Comment: "then there's no direct mapping between Java classes and GraphQL types" : this line changed everything and now I am able to use GraphQL properly.
- Thanks a lot

Comment: Best reaction I've ever got! You're most welcome!